# Can android box turn TV on/off?

Tags: android, hdmi

I have android TV box with CEC.
How can I able to turn On/Off TV or Dim/Standby that connect with the box on HDMI port?

I read about with CEC but not found command for control power of TV .
[Android CEC Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4e90fcd/core/java/android/hardware/hdmi/HdmiCec.java)

Comment: CEC generally turns on the tv when a substantive action is taken.

Comment: the problem is I need to control turn On/Off by my android application.

Comment: have you get any solution about this?